# Differences between WifiConfiguration status

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-wifi, android-4.2-jelly-bean, wifi

What is the difference between WifiConfiguration.Status = CURRENT and ENABLED? I can figure for DISABLED but the difference between CURRENT and ENABLED is not obvious to me.

Also, for a given connected network, 4.0.3 doesn't give me the save status as 4.0.4 and 4.2.2 give me. The former gives me ENABLED while the later give me CURRENT. Someone knows why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Javadoc for the `Status` class:

```
/** this is the network we are currently connected to */
public static final int CURRENT = 0;

/** supplicant will not attempt to use this network */
public static final int DISABLED = 1;

/** supplicant will consider this network available for association */
public static final int ENABLED = 2;
```

So if 4.0.3 isn't returning `CURRENT` for the currently connected network, that seems likely to be a bug that was fixed in 4.0.4.

Comment: Do you know how this bug can be bypassed in applications? If I can detect the right network that *should* be CURRENT, can I force the value to CURRENT? My point is that further API methods like ServerSocket.accept() will fail with 4.0.3 and I suspect this can be the bug that causes this failure.

Comment: I don't know for sure that it's actually an OS bug, but if so you might be able to just manually update the state and save the configuration. I'm not sure of anything past that, though.